# Having troubles having a rewrite not rewrite for something

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I made a rewrite that rewrote the string, `site.com/foo`, to `site.com/?loc=foo.php`. It works fine, but when I enter `site.com/foo.php`, instead of rewriting to `site.com/?loc=foo.php.php`, it rewrites to something else that shows `site.com/?loc=foo.php` except without CSS. I want it to rewrite it as `site.com/?loc=foo.php.php`.

I have an `index.php` that reads `$loc` and includes `foo.php`.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ ?loc=$1.php
```

Troubleshoot:

I echoed `$loc` on `index.php` and there was no feedback at all. I then echoed `$loc` on `foo.php` and found out that `$loc` was not declared. This leads to the conclusion that `site.com/foo.php` is not being rewritten for some reason in the above code.

Comment: When you say `$loc`, do you mean `$_GET['loc']`?

Comment: No, `$loc` is the PHP variable that should be set if the URL is rewritten as `site.com/?loc=foo.php`. Just a coincidence between the variable name choice.

Comment: But you are reading `$_GET['loc']` into `$loc`, right? `$loc` won't be automatically set.

Comment: No, but I have been able to read `$loc` without using $_GET['loc']. In fact, it works if I do not add the `.php`. I just tried it and `$_GET['loc'] did not change anything.

Comment: My guess is that the `.` is being interpreted incorrectly by the browser. You should url-encode it as `%2E`, and use PHP's `urldecode()` function.

Comment: You only do the rewrite when the file does not actually exist, as the first line says. So if you have a `foo.php` there, it will be executed and no rewrite happens. Also you should not use the automatic parsing of parameters like `loc=` to local variables, as that is a security issue. So turn `register_globals` off if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The script you have should work fine. Here's what I tested with.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ ?loc=$1.php
```

This means:

1) You have another parameter in .htaccess that interferes. Comment out (with #) any lines other than the above. Then pull them back in, one by one (or as few as possible) until you find the culpret.

2) loc.php actually exists. the -f means "if the file does not exist"

3) When you generate $loc, you are excluding the varaible for some reason. You can check by adding the top to your index.php file. The first line shows you the get (should be 'lol'=>'loc.php.php') and the second line shows you all the confertions that have gone on:

```
<?php
  print_r($_GET);
  echo '<br><br>';
  print_r($_SERVER);
?>
```

Comment: Thank you. The file did exist, I put the files in `includes` and had them included that way.